# Scrapy: Limit the number of request or request bytes

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using a scrapy `CrawlSpider` and defined a twisted reactor to control my crawler. During the tests I crawled a news site collecting more than several GBs of data. Mostly I am interested in the newest stories so I am looking for a way to limit the number of requested pages, bytes or seconds.

**Is there a common way to define a limit of**

- **request_bytes**
- **request_counts** or
- **run time in seconds?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrapy Limit Requests For Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928177/scrapy-limit-requests-for-testing)

Comment: @OfirD Why do you flag this question as a duplicate if it is older (2013) than your suggestion (2015) and has more upvotes? Is not the other question a duplicate.

Comment: [Age shouldn't matter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252930/3002584), we should favor [better questions and better answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252017/3002584). In my opinion, the duplicate has a better answer (given by the user alecxe), as it focuses on the one relevant setting, and is citing its documentation, while yours just lists every possible setting related to closing the spider, without really answering your own question. That's my opinion, others may see it differently.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In `scrapy` there is the class `scrapy.extensions.closespider.CloseSpider`. 
You can define the variables `CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT`, `CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT`, `CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT` and `CLOSESPIDER_ERRORCOUNT`.

The spider closes automatically when the criteria is met:
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#module-scrapy.extensions.closespider

Comment: is there a way CLOSESIPDER_PAGECOUNT can be set dynamically for each spider?