# Scrapy Limit Requests For Testing

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I've been searching the scrapy documentation for a way to limit the number of requests my spiders are allowed to make. During development I don't want to sit here and wait for my spiders to finish an entire crawl, even though the crawls are pretty focused they can still take quite awhile.

I  want the ability to say, "After x requests to the site I'm scraping stop generating new requests."

I was wondering if there is a setting for this I may have missed or some other way to do it using the framework before I try to come up with my own solution.

I was considering implementing a downloader middleware that would keep track of the number of requests being processed and stop passing them to the downloader once a limit has been reached. But like I said I'd rather use a mechanism already in the framework if possible.

Any thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for the [`CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT` setting of the `CloseSpider` extension](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#closespider-pagecount):

> An integer which specifies the maximum number of responses to crawl.
>   If the spider crawls more than that, the spider will be closed with
>   the reason `closespider_pagecount`. If zero (or non set), spiders won’t
>   be closed by number of crawled responses.

Comment: Awesome. I'll try this when I get to the office tomorrow. Thanks so much.

Comment: Use it like `scrapy crawl myspider -s CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT=10` to set it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to @alecxe's answer, it's worth noting that:

> Requests which are currently in the downloader queue (up to
> `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` requests) are still processed.

Although the above documentation is currently present only for `CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT` (and not `CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT`), it should also appear there, because that's how it works.

One can verify it with the following code:

```
# scraper.py

from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy import Request

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'MySpider'
    custom_settings = {'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 2}

    def start_requests(self):
        data_urls = [
          'https://www.example.com', 'https://www.example1.com', 'https://www.example2.com'
        ]
        for url in data_urls:
            yield Request(url=url, callback=lambda res: print(res))
```

Assuming all 3 requests were yielded before two responses were already returned (this happened to me in 100% of times I tested it), the third request (to `example2.com`) would still get executed, so that running it:

```
scrapy runspider scraper.py
```

... will output (note how although the spider went into a `Closing spider` stage, `GET https://example2.com` was still executed):

```
INFO: Scrapy 2.3.0 started (bot: scrapybot)  
[...]  
INFO: Overridden settings:  
{'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 2, 'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True}
[...]  
INFO: Spider opened
[...]
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com> (referer: None)
<200 https://www.example.com>
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example1.com> (referer: None)
INFO: Closing spider (closespider_pagecount)
<200 https://www.example1.com>
DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://example2.com/> from <GET https://www.example2.com>
INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 647,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 3659,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 11.052137,
 'finish_reason': 'closespider_pagecount',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 4, 11, 28, 41, 801185),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 4, 11, 28, 30, 749048)}
INFO: Spider closed (closespider_pagecount)
```

This can be prevented by simply introducing an instance variable (e.g., `limit`):

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy import Request

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'MySpider'
    limit = 2

    def start_requests(self):
        data_urls = [
           'https://www.example.com', 'https://www.example1.com', 'https://www.example2.com'
        ]
        for url in data_urls:
            if self.limit > 0:
                yield Request(url=url, callback=lambda res: print(res))
                self.limit -= 1
```

So that now only 2 requests are queued and executed. Output:

```
[...]
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com> (referer: None)
<200 https://www.example.com>
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example1.com> (referer: None)
<200 https://www.example1.com>
INFO: Closing spider (closespider_pagecount)
INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 431,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 3468,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 5.827646,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 4, 11, 29, 41, 801185),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 4, 11, 29, 30, 749048)}
INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```