# Stop Scrapy after N items scraped

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm having trouble with Scrapy.  I need code that will scrap up to 1000 internal links per given url.  My code works when run at command line, but the spider doesn't stop, only receives the message.

My code is as follows:

```
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.contrib.closespider import CloseSpider

class MyItem(Item):
    url= Field()

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'testspider1'
    allowed_domains = ['angieslist.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.angieslist.com']

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse_url', follow=True), )

    def parse_url(self, response):
        item = MyItem()
        item['url'] = response.url

        scrape_count = self.crawler.stats.get_value('item_scraped_count')
        print scrape_count

        limit = 10

        if scrape_count == limit:
            raise CloseSpider('Limit Reached')

        return item
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't stop? I believe scrapy will contrinue to process already requests items after CloseSpider was recieved. I mean, it won't stop immediately, but no new items will be requested

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928177/scrapy-limit-requests-for-testing) could be interesting for you.

Comment: You're right, it does stop.  But, I'm planning to scale this process up and would like to remove any unnecessary processing.  I was hoping that there would be some way to "stop on a dime." so to speak.

Comment: Also, why don't you use http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#closespider-itemcount

Comment: Frank, I think you found what I need.  I'm just trying to figure out how to implement / test it.  Alik, I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My problem was trying to apply close spider in the wrong place.  It's a variable that needs to be set in the settings.py file.  When I set it manually in there, or set it as a argument in the command line, it worked (Stopping within 10-20 of N for what it's worth).

settings.py:

```
BOT_NAME = 'internal_links'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['internal_links.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'internal_links.spiders'
CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT = 1000
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['internal_links.pipelines.CsvWriterPipeline']
# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
USER_AGENT = 'yo mama'
LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'
```

Comment: I have implemented the same methodology, and as you say, it is stopping between `10-20` of the desired value. Do you know why this is? For completeness, I want my spider to stop instantly!

Comment: From what I remember, the process is async and therefore not immediate when making request to the process.  It's been a long time though and I'm working on memory, so this may not be the case anymore.

Comment: at least you crawled responsibly by identifying yourself in the user agent