# Scrapy have a item limit?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, web-crawler, scrapy

in those days i'm making a Spider with Scrapy in Python.
It's basically a simple spider class, that make simple parsing of some field in a Html page.
I don't use the starts_url[] Scrapy field, but i use a personalized list like this:

```
class start_urls_mod():
def __init__(self, url, data):
    self.url=url
    self.data=data

#Defined in the class:
url_to_scrape = []
#Populated in the body in this way
self.url_to_scrape.append(start_urls_mod(url_found), str(data_found))
```

passing the url in this way

```
for any_url in self.url_to_scrape:
    yield scrapy.Request(any_url.url, callback=self.parse_page)
```

It works good with a limited numbers of url like 3000.

But if i try to make a test and it found about 32532 url to scrape.
In the JSON output file i found only about 3000 url scraped.

My function recall it self:

```
yield scrapy.Request(any_url.url, callback=self.parse_page)
```

So the question is, there is some memory limit for the Scrapy items?

Comment: Theres a whole section in the manual about memory usage limits. The problem is when calling random url's that you might find someones hosting a 1gb file .. that could severly break your server thats pulling.  Do you have the Memory usage extension turned on, (see http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#topics-extensions-ref-memusage )

Comment: @JamesTaylor So i need to increase the MEMUSAGE_LIMIT_MB and set a high value in order to not stop the program ?

Comment: If you're hitting a memory limit, Scrapy/Python would throw an exception indicating so.  If it does, determine why it's using the memory that it is  35k Requests isn't that many to have sitting there (they aren't all that big).  Scrapy shouldn't be holding onto response objects or items for much longer than it takes to process them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrapy Limit Requests For Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928177/scrapy-limit-requests-for-testing)

Answer (score 2):

No, if you haven't specified [CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#closespider-itemcount) on your settings.

maybe scrapy is finding duplicates in your requests, please check if that stats contain something like `dupefilter/filtered` on your logs.