# Limit number of links scraped by SimpleHtmlDOM

Tags: php, web-crawler, simple-html-dom

I would like to crawl links from news websites, but I would like to limit how many links I actually scrape (e.g. top 10 newest articles, not all links on the homepage).

I saw that you can set a limit on how many bytes or how long the crawler is active, but also that there exists an "itemcount" which can stop the crawler once a certain number of items are reached ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19160594/scrapy-limit-the-number-of-request-or-request-bytes)). However that is for Scrapy, which is Python based.

I am using [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_dump), so PHP. Does anyone know of something similar?

Alternatively, is it possible to scrape links without limit and import it into a file, then extract the top 10 links from that file?

If there is an obvious answer to this, I apologize - I am an absolute amateur, this is my first small project.

Here is the code I am using, not sure if that helps:

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$target_url = "https://www.example.com/";

$html = new simple_html_dom();

$html->load_file($target_url);
foreach($html->find('div[class=article]') as $post)
{
$post->find('div[class=title]',0)->outertext = ";
echo $post."<br />";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First. You have syntax error

Replace

```
$post->find('div[class=title]',0)->outertext = ";
```

with

```
$post->find('div[class=title]',0)->outertext = "";
```

To limit it no **n** items, just break out of `foreach` if limit is met.

```
$limit = 10;
foreach($html->find('div[class=article]') as $i => $post)
{
  $post->find('div[class=title]',0)->outertext = "";
  echo $post."<br />";
  $i++;

  if($i++ >= $limit){
    break;
  }
}
```

Like @ElzoValugi suggested, `for` suites better here.

```
$posts = $html->find('div[class=article]');
$limit = 10;
$limit = count($posts) < $limit ? count($posts) : $limit;
for($i=0; $i < $limit; $i++){
  $post = $posts[$i];
  $post->find('div[class=title]',0)->outertext = "";
  echo $post."<br />";
}
```

Comment: a for loop is actually more suited than the foreach in this case

Comment: Guys thank you so much. I really (!) appreciate the help.

Comment: Actually the foreach was better, but the break was a little clumsy. How about `if($i++ >= $limit) break;`

Comment: Also instead of initializing $i, just use the keys: `foreach($elements as $i => $element)`

Comment: @pguardiario Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have found **simple_html_dom** pretty good and useful.
You can actually get elements with jQuery type selectors.

If you can find a class to all new post you can run something like this

```
$links = $html->find('a.<class name>').
```

Or you just want 10 first 10 items.

```
$links = $html->find('a:lt(10)'); // I have not tested it.
// Or 
$links = $html->find('a');
$count = count($links);
for($i = 10; $i < $count ; $i++){
    $links[$i]->remove();
}
```

There plently more things in this package.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will try this out asap!

Comment: while you can use most of CSS selectors with this library, I don't think _lt()_ type selector will will work, because this a non standard jQuery selector